# Obtener latitud y longitud con javascript y enviarlo a php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener la latitud y longitud desde javascript, para posteriormente capturarlo en php una vez que la web haya cargado, el problema está en que no logro capturar el valor desde js.
Como podría capturar los valores de latitud y longitud en la misma página PHP una vez esta haya cargado ?

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) 
{
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
} 
else 
{
   alert("¡Error! Este navegador no soporta la Geolocalización.");
}
function mostrarUbicacion(position)
{
   var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
   var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
   var div = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
   div.innerHTML =  latitud + "<br>" + longitud 
}
```

```html
<div id="ubicacion"></div>
```

como pasaria las variables latitud y longitud a PHP

Comment: El código como texto por favor

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta, quitar la foto y añadir el código. En caso contrario te cerrarán tu pregunta

Comment: listo!, ya modifique

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y funciona. Pero debes darle a "Permitir" cuando te pregunta por el permiso

Comment: La geolocacion necesita permisos del usuario, asi que verifica que no tienes un iconito de ubicacion con una x en la barra de direcciones, e igualmente el metodo getCurrentPosition recibe 3 parametros, success que es el que usas, error y options, mira masde esto en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: no se si entendieron mi pregunta , con ese codigo si obtengo las latitudes y longitudes, mi dificultad esta en eniar esa latitud y longitud a una variable de PHP para luego insertarlas en mysql

Comment: Entonces debes colocar el código de esa parte.